# How to draw custom painter not in stack in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am learning custom painter in Flutter to create my own pie chart. I draw a circle first and then draw an arc for each percentage in the list. The problem is that the arcs are in stacks. I want the arcs to draw next to the previous arc. How could I implement it? And also I want to appear their percentage in the center of each arc.

Following is my code and the screenshot of the pie chart I created:

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Color randomColor =
    Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);

class PieChart extends CustomPainter {
  List<int> percent = [50, 20, 30];

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    double radius = math.min(size.width / 2, size.height);

    // center point of the size
    Offset center = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);

    // draw circle
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paint);

    for (int i = 0; i < percent.length; i++) {
      // set the angle of the arc
      double arcAngle = 2 * math.pi * (percent[i] / 100);

      // change random color
      paint.color = randomColor =
          Color((math.Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt())
              .withOpacity(1.0);

      // draw the arc
      canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromCircle(center: center, radius: radius),
          -math.pi / 2, arcAngle, true, paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(PieChart oldDelegate) => false;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuildSemantics(PieChart oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[Pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJzUI.png)

Comment: this is because you use `-math.pi / 2` for every arc

Comment: Oh i see.. How should I change that part to work as I want?

Comment: you need to create a variable `startAngle` and after each loop iteration you need to add `arcAngle` to it